# Finding "main" functions' names in a C file via Bash script

Tags: c, regex, bash, unix, grep

I'm having a large number of C files, that are structured with the following principle:

- All functions are declared in the C file and are with return type int, double or void.
- All functions start with "ksz_". Only functions use this - nothing else uses "ksz_" in their names.
- The file contains "main" functions. All supporting functions use their "main" function's name to form themselves.
- Because they were made by different people they are quite messly made and have spaces placed at random places:

A rought visualization would be(note the spaces):

```
int ksz_Print(...)
{
...
}

void  ksz_Print_Helper1 (... ){
...
}
 void ksz_Print_Helper2(...) {
...
}
int ksz_Input(...){
...
}
double ksz_Input_Helper1  ( ...){
...
}
```

I need to find the "main" function names of each individual C file in order to use them for another seach algorithm.
Since these files are huge(sme of them have over a dozen thousand lines) and there are hundreds of them - I need a Bash scrip for this.

Ideally this script would extract only the "main" functions:

```
ksz_Print
ksz_Input
```

What stops me is that i can't think the **Regex** of my **grep** in order to extract the function lines. I think its logic should look like this:

(spaces)(int/float/double)(spaces)(ksz_)(other characers without space)(spaces)(open bracket)

After that I guess I'll extract the word containing "ksz_" from each line with **cut**(after trimming and removing duplicate spaces).

And last I'll need to find a way to filter out the supporting functions.

But what would be my initial grep in this script?

Comment: I'm afraid it's going to be extremely hard to do with regular expressions. Have you considered using `gtags`, `ctags` or something similar?

Comment: Something like `grep -E '\b(int|float|double)\s+ksz_[A-Za-z0-9]\s*\('` should get you started.

Comment: I think regular expressions are able to parse regular grammars only. While C is based on a context-free grammar..

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with gtags, ctags thats why i never considered them. And about the Regex from Coladict - yea its a good start, but i'm not sure if that is sufficient for now(by the way you missed the * after [A-Z...])
Eugene Sh - not sure what you mean, i treat the files as txt files and the regex from above works quite well.

Comment: @YaniMaltsev Grammars theory is a whole discipline in CS (and linguistics, perhaps). Familiarize yourself if you wish. In short - there are different "ranks" of grammars. The lowest is the "regular" one, which can be described by regular expressions. Context-free is the higher rank. It cannot be described by regular expressions.

Comment: Yes i know, but these files follow very specific structure, they don't use pointers for return type, anything outside of int/double/void - they follow this very specific structure. So a regular expression should be sufficient in this case.

Comment: It might be easier to parse the *object* files using `nm` or `objdump` and then use `grep` on the result. That way you don't have to worry about the difference between a function declaration, function definition and function call - you will only get function definitions.

Comment: Do the names of any main functions contain underscores, other than exactly one in the "ksz_" prefix?

Comment: Are you prepared to assume that "function lines" are not, in fact, multilines?  Do you have to worry about function names or declarations being produced with the help of the preprocessor?  Is there any possibility of universal character names appearing in your function names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your specifications correctly this should do it:

```
root@local [~]# awk '/^[ \t]*(int|float|double)[ \t]+ksz_/ {print $2}' sample.txt
```

One thing I did not understand was whether there should only be one "_" after ksz so for example if "double ksz_Input_Helper1" is not something you want to match. In the regex above it does match.

I also chose to go with awk rather than grep as you said you want only the name the above awk prints only the second field using whitespace as a delimiter. If you still want to use grep this one does the same task:

```
root@local [~]# egrep '^\s*(int|float|double)\s+ksz_' sample.txt
```

Here is a breakdown(note in awk I use [ \t] in place of \s as I could not get it to recognize \s]:

```
^ - match start of line
\s* - match if there are 0 or more white spaces
(int|float|double) - match int, float, OR double
\s+ - match at least one whitespace
ksz_ - match literal string "ksz_"
```

Comment: How does that select the "main" functions from among all the others?

Comment: What if the function name appears on a different line than its return type?

Comment: Based on what the OP is saying it seems to me that they can set it to not match anything that has more than 1 underscore OR use what I provided and set it to not match an underscore after the "ksz_" section so ksz_\w[^_] or something along those lines.

Comment: The actual question is for the initial grep. The main can be filtered afterwards onse you know all function names. I simply can't do even simple regex like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex that only matches the portion you want and only print that:

```
grep -oRE "(ksz_[a-zA-Z_]*\b)" *
   -o - output only match
   -R - recursive
   -E - regex
   [a-zA-Z_] - upper and lower case letters, underscore
   \b - ending at word boundry
```

Comment: That does not appear to satisfy the OP's objective of selecting only the "main" functions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Oh I see. I'll update the regex shortly